# Use JS/jQuery To Animate Letters In Element One-By-One

Tags: javascript, jquery

### What I'm Trying To Achieve:

With a wrapper for a display plane and an inner element with any text within;

1. **Calculate center;**

   - Get width of wrapper
   - Get width of text prior separation
   - ( Wrapper width / 2 ) - Text width  = where first letter will go
2. **Break up text into own div elements** *- I don't require but for anyone looking to use any answers, you may want to replace spaces for `&nbsp;`*
3. **Set position of each letter container to be outside of container to the right**
4. **Animate each letter elements margin with an end ease effect;**

   - First to middle position
   - All following to end position minus total widths of already moved letters.
5. **Hold for a couple of seconds**
6. **Each letter element does the same going outside of the plane to the left with a slight delay.**
7. **Repeat**

---

### In A Less Confusing Nut Shell

Each letter comes on with a slightly delayed starting time to the center of the wrapper, holds there and then goes out of the viewport. I am personally doing this for a loading animation.

---

### My Attempt So Far:

```
<div class="LoadWrap">
    <div class="Loading">Loading</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/JS/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/JS/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var Elem = $('.Loading'),
            EWid = Elem.width(),
            EStr = Elem.html(),
            ESLe = EStr.length,
            EOWi = Elem.parent().width(),
            ABCD = (EOWi - EWid) / 2,
            CTWi = 0;

        Elem.html("");

        for (var i = 0, len = ESLe; i < len; i++) {
          Elem.append("<div style=\"margin-left: " + EOWi + "px;\">" + EStr[i] + "</div>");
        }
        for (var i = 0, len = ESLe; i < len; i++) {
            var ThisWidth = $(".Loading > div:nth-of-type(i)").width();
            console.log(ThisWidth);
            //setTimeout(
            //  function() {
            //      $("#full-wrapper #full").animate({
            //          marginLeft: '-=938px'
            //      },{
            //          easing: 'easing',
            //          duration: 250,
            //      });
            //  }, 500);
        }

    });
</script>
```

---

### Problems I'm Experiencing:

1. ':nth-of-type( number )' seems to work however `:nth-of-type(i)` will not.

Comment: $(".Loading > div:nth-of-type("+i+")")

Comment: Tim: have a look at this comment ^^^^^^ above - nothing sad here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the number

```
var ThisWidth = $(".Loading > div:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").width();
```